# To save object that has projected materials as glb file

Tags: three.js, projection-matrix

I have three.js app that project images to object.
Now I want to save that object as glb file.

Here is an issue. The projected material is not saved. I can't see it when I open the saved glb file with Blender.

```
           object.traverse(function (child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    
                    child.material = material1
                    child.material.needsUpdate = true
                    material1.project(child)
                    
                    scene1.add(child)
                    const exporter = new Exporter();
                    exportBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                      exporter.exportScene(child);
                    })
                }
            }
```

It is not uv mapping, it's project 'mapping'.
What do I miss? What should I do now? Please help me.

Comment: What type of material do you assign to the mesh? I'm asking since not all materials are supported by `GLTFExporter`. Besides, it would be easier to investigate the issue if you share a live example that demonstrates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/g3atw6k5/

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks. But I can't share the code because it's pretty big. Anyway I use ProjectedMaterial. If GLTFExporter doesn't support ProjectMaterial, what is the another option?

Comment: This material is not support by `GLTFExporter`. It best to use `MeshStandardMaterial` or `MeshBasicMaterial`.

Comment: @Mugen87 My project's goal is to project image at the mesh, so that I need to use ProjectedMaterial. What other exporter that supports ProjectedMaterial can I use? Or Can I use other material to project image at the mesh? What effect I want can find this link. In addition of that, I want to export the object as GLB or any other 3d file with materials. https://codesandbox.io/s/projected-material-with-resize-and-gesture-handler-z86sd?file=/src/index.js:1731-1739

Comment: The problem is that exporters rely on the specification that they are exporting to. `ProjectedMaterial` is a custom material that does not exist in this form in any 3D file format. So you need to find a way how to achieve the same effect with `MeshStandardMaterial`. It might be possible to do the same by manipulating the texture coordinates but I don't know a adhoc solution for this.

Comment: @Mugen87 As you said, `ProjectedMaterial` is not a standard material so I left it and I am finding new solution with `MeshBasicMaterial`. Now I faced new problem.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188414/play-with-texture-in-three-js]. II need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProjectedMaterial` does not get exported when you export Mesh with `GLTFExporter`, because it's real-time shader. Leave `ProjectedMaterial`. You can get the same effect with `MeshBasicMaterial`. Please try with uv mapping. You can get projection effect as you adjust uv property of the geometry. Keep texture map and other properties of the mesh geometry.
You need to concern the image scale and offset.

Comment: Good idea, Thank you.