# Play with Texture in three js

Tags: three.js, mapping, textures, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

everyone. I want to know if it is possible to map specific triangle region of one texture to the another triangle of other texture with different size and shape in three.js?
[image]
I am new to three.js so I don’t know well how to implement it with three js code. Please help me. I need sample code snippet.